# Changing color with calendar according to half day and full day using android-times-square api in android

Tags: android, calendar

I am developing an android app with android-times-square API. for this i am using https://github.com/square/android-times-square url to developed custom calendar into my app.

I have successful integrated that API. but i want some changes using this API.

I want changing color according to half day and full day selection.

**below is my screen:**

[image]

I have used following manner for solved this issue. I have resolve this issue but for this steps my app is going to hang.

There are following steps:

1: (Replace default line to my modified line)

**Default:**

```
  calendar.setDecorators(Collections.<CalendarCellDecorator>emptyList());
```

**Replaced**

```
  List<CalendarCellDecorator> decoratorList = new ArrayList<>();
  decoratorList.add(new MonthDecorator());
  calendar.setDecorators(decoratorList);
```

2. MonthDecorator.java

```
public class MonthDecorator implements CalendarCellDecorator {

    @Override
    public void decorate(CalendarCellView calendarCellView, Date date) {

           /**
     * getting value from tag
     */
    String mDate = calendarCellView.getTag().toString().split("\\{")[1].split(",")[0].split("=")[1];

    /**
     * getting value from shared preference
     */
    HashMap<Date, String> mList = GeneralUtil.GetCalenderView(calendarCellView.getContext());


    if(mList != null){

        if(mList.size()>0){
            for(int y=0 ; y<mList.size();y++){
                /**
                 * getting keys from hashmap
                 */
                String Format = "",mValue="";
                Format = mList.keySet().toArray()[y].toString();
                /////////////////

                /**
                 * getting value from hashmap
                 */
                mValue = mList.entrySet().toArray()[y].toString();
                //////////////////

                /**
                 * compare value from saved half day and retrive date
                 */
                if(Format.equals(mDate)){

                    if(mValue.split("=")[1].equals("0")){
                        calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector_green);
                        mTempCheckDate.add(""+Format);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    if(!mTempCheckDate.contains(Format)){
                        calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);
                    }

                }
                ////////////////////////

            }
        }
        else{
            calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);
        }


    }
    else{
        calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);
    }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have solved this issue to some extent. but My custom calendar not scroll smoothly.

I am using following code in MonthDecoder.java file:

```
 public class MonthDecorator implements CalendarCellDecorator {

    @Override
    public void decorate(final CalendarCellView calendarCellView, Date date) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                callFxnForChangeColor(calendarCellView);
                }
        },0);

    }

    private void callFxnForChangeColor(CalendarCellView calendarCellView) {
        /**
         * getting value from tag
         */
        String mDate = calendarCellView.getTag().toString().split("\\{")[1].split(",")[0].split("=")[1];

        /**
         *  convert date from one formatg to another format
         */
        mDate = Utils.callFxnForConvertDateToString(new Date(mDate));

        /**
         * getting value from shared preference
         */
        HashMap<String, String> mList = GeneralUtil.GetCalenderView(calendarCellView.getContext());

        if(mList != null && mList.size()>0){

            if (mList.containsKey(mDate)){
                calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector_green);

            }
            else{
                calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);

            }
        }
        else{
            calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);
        }
    }
}
```

So, Can anyone suggest me for resolve this problem.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by my self. I have changed some changes in  **MonthDecorator.java** file and **internal adapter class**.

There are following changing:

1. **CalendarPickerView.java ("MonthAdapter" Adapter class)**

   ```
    if(monthView == null){
           monthView =
                   MonthView.create(
                           parent,
                           inflater,
                           weekdayNameFormat,
                           listener,
                           today,
                           dividerColor,
                           dayBackgroundResId,
                           dayTextColorResId,
                           titleTextColor,
                           displayHeader,
                           headerTextColor,
                           decorators,
                           locale,
                           dayViewAdapter);

           monthView.setTag(R.id.day_view_adapter_class, dayViewAdapter.getClass());
       }
       else{
           monthView.getTag(R.id.day_view_adapter_class);
       }

     monthView.setDecorators(decorators);
   ```
2. **MonthDecorator .java**

   ```
   public class MonthDecorator implements CalendarCellDecorator {

   @Override
   public void decorate(final CalendarCellView calendarCellView, Date date) {

       final Handler handler = new Handler();

       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               callFxnForChangeColor(calendarCellView);
               }
       },0);
   }

   private void callFxnForChangeColor(CalendarCellView calendarCellView) {
       /**
        * getting value from tag
        */
       String mDate = calendarCellView.getTag().toString().split("\\{")[1].split(",")[0].split("=")[1];

       /**
        *  convert date from one formatg to another format
        */
       mDate = Utils.callFxnForConvertDateToString(new Date(mDate));

       /**
        * getting value from shared preference
        */
       HashMap<String, String> mList = GeneralUtil.GetCalenderView(calendarCellView.getContext());

       if(mList != null && mList.size()>0){

           if (mList.containsKey(mDate)){
               calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector_green);

           }
           else{
               calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);

           }
       }
       else{
           calendarCellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_bg_selector);
       }
   }
   }
   ```